# Flipping an old manual switch (physical one)

Tags: motor, raspberry-pi, robotic-arm

I Have an old [audio amplifier](http://www.hifido.co.jp/photo/10/520/52010/b.jpg) that has those switches to turn it on. 
I'm looking for the simplest motor/robotic arm (or any other relevant component) to control this switch - eventually via Raspberry Pi .

Are there any options ?

Comment: Must you keep the switch or can you replace it with a relay?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/pushing-buttons-remotely-over-ethernet) as well

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to control the switches and not the knobs, some options are:

- Dual acting solenoids or two simple acting [solenoids](http://www.magnetschultz.co.uk/uploads/images/product_images/return-springs-l.jpg). 

  Needs just a pulse of current in one direction to operate. In some dual acting solenoids, you need to reverse current to reverse the direction of force.

  <sup>Image from http://www.magnetschultz.co.uk</sup>
- RC servo-motor. *(With that you can control the knobs too)*

  Normally more force for a given size/weight of solenoid. Slower than a solenoid but depending on the model still in the $ ms $ for a 60° rotation. Has more moving parts than a solenoid, so more wear. Major ones have a brushed DC motor so have the brushes wear too. Anyway, should last for maybe a decade without problem. It's a servo-mechanism, so has position feedback and precision positioning. Have the drive electronics, but you need to provide a PWM signal relative to the position you want it to rotate.
- [Car door lock actuator](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41dI3XxmxWL._SX300_.jpg)
  Shares some of the properties from a RC Servo-motor, but has linear action like the solenoid, and don't have position feed-back (some have a open/closed feed-back). Needs a pulse of current to operate too, but needs reversing the current to reverse the direction of force.

  <sup>Image from http://www.amazon.com/</sup>

---

<sup>**Note:** I presume by your question that you want to mechanical actuate the switch and electronic options are excluded.</sup>